# Do I require transit visa for UK & Brazil

Tags: visas, uk, transit, brazil, sri-lankan-citizens

I am a Sri Lankan passport holder with a Finnish study residence permit, I will be changing my flight at Heathrow airport (London) on the 14/07/2016 (transit of 1.5 hours - terminal 3) from Finnair to TAM Linhas Aereas flying to Chile through Brazil. Would I need a transit visa for London and Sao Paulo?

Comment: @blackbird57 That doesn't cover the Sao Paulo element though.

Comment: @CMaster ok so half the question is a possible duplicate :)

Comment: Are you changing flights in Brazil? Which airport? Which flights?

Comment: @dinu the UK part of the question already has an answer on the site. Let's make this one about the brasil transit visa.

Comment: hey it's Guarulh airport SAO PAULO, BRAZIL

Comment: @CMaster it's a duplicate.  The OP can ask about Brazil in a new question